# Peer to peer library for the browser

Tags: javascript, flash, html

The options for peer-to-peer connections in the browser I can think of are WebRTC (PeerConnection), Flash/Java/Silverlight.

Considering WebRTC is not mass implemented, I decided to go for the Flash option, but my app is HTML5-based, so I found this
https://github.com/empaempa/P2P.js

I am not sure if it is suitable for my purpose (VNC/RDP) but I am about to find out.

The point is - is there a **library** that unifies peer-to-peer options in the browser with a JavaScript interface. I want the same that socket.io does for sockets - first tries WebSocket, then falls back to flash emulation, then to AJAX, etc.
However, this should be for P2P connections - first try WebRTC, then try Flash, then Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a library that tries Javascript then Flash. I recommend you find a library that works well with Javascript OR Flash and just use that.

Normally, I'd say go with Javascript and HTML5, but you mention VNC/RDP, which involves video. Depending on the use case, Flash sometimes handles video better. If however you're just receiving and play video, and sending back commands over a socket, then HTML5 will do.